# level 0 key values not getting stored in level 1 record

Tags: scroll, structure, record, area, peoplesoft

I have a page which has level 0 and 1 with two different records

```
Level 0 record - PD_PRF_TYP 
Fields - Emplid (key)
             Region (key)
             Prof_typ (key)
Level 1 record - PD_CONT_TYP
Fields -Emplid (key)
             Region (key)
             Prof_typ (key
             Cat_typ (key)
```

Whenever I am trying to add scroll data the key fields from level 0 record are getting saved only for first row of scroll. Rest all rows are getting saved with only emplid, cat_typ

```
Example of data
Level0
Emplid - b1245 Region - TWN Prof_typ - PERS 

Level 1 
Row 1 - Emplid - b1245 Region - TWN Prof_typ - PERS  Cat_typ -EDU
Row 2- Emplid - b1245 Region - Blank Prof_typ - Blank Cat_typ -EDU-TMP
```

Comment: Do you display the level 1 fields that are not saved? Try showing them in the scroll on the page and see if they get filled.

Comment: Tried displaying the fields on level 1. Gets filled only for row 1.

Comment: And the 'occurs level' is 1? See if 'page order' is correct.

Comment: Yes occurs level is 1

Comment: Try removing the level 1 record and then re-add it.  Then check the order tab to make use the records and fields are in the correct order.

Comment: Tried removing level 1 and re adding, still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen at times and never figured out why. However, I had success in solving it by setting the level 1 Record's key fields' default values to the corresponding level 0 Record Fields.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old, but if anyone needs to know: I figured out why this happens:
If you are using the Level 0 record also as the component search record, the level 0 key of the record **must** be a Search Key field.

It was happening to a brand-new component I built with two-deep scroll levels (1 and 2), and just making the record key field also be a Search Key field eliminated this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).